# Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant

Tags: spring-boot, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am migrating my spring boot application from ADAL to MSAL.

I am getting the error shown below:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: 
AADSTS50194: Application 'fd0ac989-0246-4999-b562-6d42d3636c22'(primadollardev_solanapi) is not configured as a multi-tenant application. 
Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. 
Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.
Trace ID: 49905cdc-df8e-4bbb-9f48-daa2fe893000
Correlation ID: d6957f88-b418-4351-b141-4a5fbb6c6a99
Timestamp: 2020-08-30 06:05:40Z
```

## ADAL CODE

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License. See LICENSE in the project root for
 * license information.
 */

    package com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad;
    
    import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;
    import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
    import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJOSEException;
    import com.nimbusds.jose.util.ResourceRetriever;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
    
    import javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
    
    public class AADAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AADAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
        private static final String CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL = "CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL";
        private static final String CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL_GRAPHAPI_TOKEN = "CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL_GRAPHAPI_TOKEN";
        private static final String CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL_JWT_TOKEN = "CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL_JWT_TOKEN";
    
        private static final String TOKEN_HEADER = "Authorization";
        private static final String TOKEN_TYPE = "Bearer ";
    
        private AADAuthenticationProperties aadAuthProps;
        private ServiceEndpointsProperties serviceEndpointsProps;
        private UserPrincipalManager principalManager;
    
        public AADAuthenticationFilter(AADAuthenticationProperties aadAuthProps,
                                       ServiceEndpointsProperties serviceEndpointsProps,
                                       ResourceRetriever resourceRetriever) {
            this.aadAuthProps = aadAuthProps;
            this.serviceEndpointsProps = serviceEndpointsProps;
            this.principalManager = new UserPrincipalManager(serviceEndpointsProps, aadAuthProps, resourceRetriever, false);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
            final String authHeader = request.getHeader(TOKEN_HEADER);
    
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith(TOKEN_TYPE)) {
                try {
                    final String idToken = authHeader.replace(TOKEN_TYPE, "");
                    UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) request
                            .getSession().getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL);
                    String graphApiToken = (String) request
                            .getSession().getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL_GRAPHAPI_TOKEN);
                    final String currentToken = (String) request
                            .getSession().getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL_JWT_TOKEN);
    
                    final ClientCredential credential =
                            new ClientCredential(aadAuthProps.getClientId(), aadAuthProps.getClientSecret());
    
                    final AzureADGraphClient client =
                            new AzureADGraphClient(credential, aadAuthProps, serviceEndpointsProps);
    
                    if (principal == null ||
                        graphApiToken == null ||
                        graphApiToken.isEmpty() ||
                        !idToken.equals(currentToken)
                    ) {
                        principal = principalManager.buildUserPrincipal(idToken);
    
                        final String tenantId = principal.getClaim().toString();
                        graphApiToken = client.acquireTokenForGraphApi(idToken, tenantId).getAccessToken();
    
                        principal.setUserGroups(client.getGroups(graphApiToken));
    
                        request.getSession().setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL, principal);
                        request.getSession().setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL_GRAPHAPI_TOKEN, graphApiToken);
                        request.getSession().setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL_JWT_TOKEN, idToken);
                    }
    
                    final Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
                            principal, null, client.convertGroupsToGrantedAuthorities(principal.getUserGroups()));
    
                    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                    log.info("Request token verification success. {}", authentication);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                } catch (MalformedURLException | ParseException | BadJOSEException | JOSEException ex) {
                    log.error("Failed to initialize UserPrincipal.", ex);
                    throw new ServletException(ex);
                } catch (ServiceUnavailableException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                    log.error("Failed to acquire graph api token.", ex);
                    throw new ServletException(ex);
                }
            }
    
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

## MSAL CODE

```
    public class MSALAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MSALAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
        private static final String TOKEN_HEADER = "Authorization";
        private static final String TOKEN_TYPE = "Bearer ";
    
        // Properties from the application.properties file like clientId, tenant and stuff.
    
        private static final String CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL = "CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL";
        private static final String CURRENT_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN = "CURRENT_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN";
    
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
            final String authHeader = request.getHeader(TOKEN_HEADER);
            UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) request.getSession().getAttribute(CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL);
    
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith(TOKEN_TYPE)) {
                try {
                    final String idToken = authHeader.replace(TOKEN_TYPE, "");
    
                    ConfidentialClientApplication clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                            clientId,
                            ClientCredentialFactory.create(clientSecret))
                            .authority(authority)
                            .build();
    
                    Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(scope.split(" ")));
                    UserAssertion assertion = new UserAssertion(idToken);
    
                    OnBehalfOfParameters params = OnBehalfOfParameters.builder(scopes, assertion).build();
                    CompletableFuture<AuthenticationResult> future = clientApplication.acquireToken(params);
    
                    AuthenticationResult accessToken = future.get();
    
                    if (principal == null) {
                        principal = principalManager.buildUserPrincipal(idToken, accessToken);
    
                        request.getSession().setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_PRINCIPAL, principal);
                        request.getSession().setAttribute(CURRENT_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
                    }
                    final Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
                            principal,
                            null,
                            convertGroupsToGrantedAuthorities(principal.getUserGroups()));
    
                    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                    log.info("Request token verification success. {}", authentication);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    
    
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                    log.error("Failed to authenticate", ex);
                    throw new ServletException(ex);
                }
    
            }    
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }    
    }
```

Please can some give me a solution......

Comment: It seems to be a version issue please refer to this  [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/842) . Let us know if it does not help you.

Comment: Sruthi should be correct. Please update to version 2.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a version issue please refer to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/842). Please update you are version to 2.2.4.